# Как сделать, чтобы прошлось по всем числам range и закончило работу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
class Kod:
    n = 1
    def sumon(self):
        running = True
        while running:
            for i in range(1, 21): #итерация по всем элементам
                if self.n % i == 0: #проверка делимости на все числа от 1 до 20
                    print(self.n) 
                    return
            else:
                self.n += 1 #В случае если число не подходит добавляет 1

Kod().sumon()
```

[image: Код в работе]

Хочу решить 5 задачу эйлера - https://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/5.html
Хочу сделать, чтобы код проходил по всем элементам `range`
и проверял, делится ли число без остатка на все элементы `range`.
И таким образом найти число, которое делится на все числа от 1 до 20.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать и возможно ли это? Если нет, то как можно заменить `range`?

Comment: отредактируйте, пожалуйста  текст. Нечитаем - все в код попало.

Comment: Вроти теперь понятно

Comment: отлично, теперь ещё хорошо бы инициализировать классически n через 'def __init__ (self):' (двойные подчеркивания не напечатались почему-то), а также обратить внимание, что первый же проход с n=1 и i=1 вызывает срабатывание return и завершение работы. На основании этого изменить код и посмотреть, что ещё не так будет работать. Советую добавить контрольные точки и наблюдать за n и i. Running можно убрать оставив просто while True.

Comment: Что-то для 20 как-то долго перебором считает, там надо наименьший общий делитель искать, перебором очень долго.

Comment: Ну 30 секунд оно работает,если тупо с перебором зделать,попытаюсь понять как найти общий наименьший делитель

Comment: советую метку python ещё добавлять, а не только 3.х

Comment: Сергей угу,щяс добавлю

Comment: 1. Отвыкайте решать проект  Эйлера простым перебором. 2. Даже, если решать перебором, то очевидно, что нет смысла проверять все числа. Результат должен делиться на 20, следовательно, можно начинать с 20 и прибавлять по 20. Ускорение в 20 раз. 2а. И проверку на деление нужно начинать не с 1 (зачем вообще проверять делимость на 1???), а с 19 и идти вниз до 7.

Comment: `math.lcm(*range(2, 21))`.

Answer (score 0):

Чего там перебирать-то?

```
20 = 2 * 2 * 5 -> 2^2 * 5
19 = 19
18 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 2 * 3^3 <- 3
17 = 17
16 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2^4 <- 2
15 = 3 * 5
14 = 2 * 7
13 = 13
11 = 11
10 = 2 * 5
 9 = 3 * 3
 8 = 2 * 2 * 2 = 2^3
 7 = 7
 6 = 2 * 3
 5 = 5
 4 = 2 * 2
 3 = 3
 2 = 2
 1 = 1
```

Смотрим на максимальные степени в наличии:

```
X = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 = 232'792'560
```

Если таки хочется перебирать, то как-то так:

```
x = 20
while True:
  fail = False
  # for d in range(11,20):
  for d in [5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19]:
    if x % d != 0:
      fail = True
      break
  if fail:
    x = x + 20
    continue
  print(f'Solution is {x}')
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 0
for i in range(40,1000000):
    for n in range(2,21):
        k = i%n
        if k == 0:
            a+=1
    if a == 19:
        print(i)
        break
    a = 0
```

Вот, как-то очень давно делал её, может тебе поможет.

Comment: Ляма маловато будет, лучше открытый внешний цикл тогда запускать